# Objective-C: Modal transition with status bar

Tags: objective-c, statusbar, modalviewcontroller

My main view controller in my app has the status bar hidden, using (in viewDidLoad):

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
```

I present a modal view, in which I would like the status bar to not be hidden, so I use (in viewWillAppear in the presented view controller):

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];
```

This works. However, it seems a little glitchy as the status bar reappears already at the top as the modal is presenting. I want the status bar to also be presented with the modal. (i.e. I want it attached with the nav bar of the view controller I am presenting)

Comment: Did you attach a navigation bar to the modal view controller you are presenting? I don't quite understand what you mean by the glitch, can you perhaps show us a screenshot?

Comment: Hi sorry I probably worded my question weird. It is the standard modal presentation, not glitchy but I would like to change it. Standardly, the status bar stays at the top of the view and the nav bar sort of meets it as it is presented mod ally. This just looks weird going from hidden to non-hidden though, so I would like the status bar to also be presented modally if possible with the rest of the view.